# Rotation of tetris block

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have another problem. I have SKSpriteNode aktualniBlock, here is code for initialization:

```
-(SKSpriteNode *)createBlock
{
    SKSpriteNode *blok = [[SKSpriteNode alloc]init];
    SKSpriteNode *square = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Red Square"];
    square.position = CGPointMake(45, 0);
    [blok addChild:square];
    square = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Red Square"];
    square.position = CGPointMake(15, 0);
    [blok addChild:square];
    square = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Red Square"];
    square.position = CGPointMake(30, 0);
    [blok addChild:square];
    square = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Red Square"];
    square.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    [blok addChild:square];
    square = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Red Square"];
    square.position = CGPointMake(45, 15);
    [blok addChild:square];

    CGRect rect = [blok calculateAccumulatedFrame];
    blok.size = CGSizeMake(rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    return blok;
}
```

When I tap it, it rotates 90 degrees :

```
-(void)tap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    [aktualniBlok setZRotation:aktualniBlok.zRotation+1.571];
}
```

But it's rotation point is not in the middle of the block, but in the left lower corner of block. How can I get it into middle of the block. I tried anchorPoint, but it didn't work.Thank you for help.

Comment: where do you set aktualniBlok?

Comment: aktualniBlok = [self createBlock];

Comment: What is the size of the red square?

Comment: Keep the parts' anchorPoint to be (0,0)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `anchorPoint` property for the `blok` node.

Set this line after calling `calculateAccumulatedFrame`:

```
CGRect rect = [blok calculateAccumulatedFrame];
blok.size = CGSizeMake(rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
blok.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
```

You can read about the `anchorPoint` property [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKSpriteNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKSpriteNode/anchorPoint).

Also, in order to set rotation, using `M_PI_2` instead of `1.571` will give you a more exact value.

Comment: I did. I set anchorPoint (0.5, 0.5), but still it rotates like anchorPoint is (0,0). Even when I manually set anchorPoint for all blok's children to (0.5, 0.5).

Comment: I tried. Doesn't work. I will try different approach and will rotate it "old" way. Thanks.

Comment: You could also set the positions of the red squares differently, by setting them with relation to a point in the center.

Answer (score 0):

AnchorPoint's of SKSprites are by default their center points.

```
[aktualniBlok setZRotation:aktualniBlok.zRotation+M_PI_2];
```

code does what you need (changing rotation with respect to its center), but if u want to change rotation of each red square with respect to their center points, you should try;

```
[square setZRotation:square.zRotation+M_PI_2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Tetris piece is not rotating about the lower-left corner. It is rotating about the center of the block at (0,0). To rotate around the center of the piece, subtract 22.5 from the x position of each block. I modified your code to make the piece rotate about its center.

```
- (SKSpriteNode *) createBlock
{
    SKSpriteNode *blok = [[SKSpriteNode alloc]init];
    SKSpriteNode *square;
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
       CGFloat x = i*15-22.5;
       square = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Red Square"];
       square.position = CGPointMake(x, 0);
       [blok addChild:square];
    }
    square = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Red Square"];
    square.position = CGPointMake(22.5, 15);
    [blok addChild:square];

    CGRect rect = [blok calculateAccumulatedFrame];
    blok.size = CGSizeMake(rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    return blok;
}
```